# Identifying a sword from an anime, possibly from One Piece or Bleach

Tags: merchandise

[image: sword image]

I got it from an anime convention thinking it was the Zoro Shusui for my cousin.

Answer (score 3):

I found a site that appears to be [selling this exact sword](http://www.acemartialartssupply.com/41-fantasy-katana-sword/)...and I hate to disappoint you, but they themselves make no reference to any anime.  It is merely a fantasy sword.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty positive that there is no character in Bleach that has a sword that looks like that.
And as for Zoro Shusui, I'm sorry to disappoint you, but it's not a very good replica.
As you can see here, this sword and its sheath looks almost completely different:[image]

Comment: darn. Thank you so much for the input. I wish I could find out what anime it is from lol